# Return a default value with scan Observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

I can read in rxjs documentation (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-scan) for the method scan there is a seed arguement.

In the below code, I would like to return a default value for _channels Observables.

```
export interface IChannelOperation extends Function {
    (channels: Channel[]): Channel[];
}
let initialChannel: Channel[] = [];

@Injectable()
export class ChannelsCatalog{
   defaultChannel: Subject<Channel> = new BehaviorSubject<Channel>(null);

   private _currentChannel: Subject<Channel> = new BehaviorSubject<Channel>(null);
   private _channels: Observable<Channel[]>;

   private _updates: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

   constructor(){
       this._channels = this._updates
           .scan((channels: Channel[], operation: IChannelOperation) => operation(channels), initialChannel)
           .publishReplay(1)
           .refCount();
   }

   getAllChannelsCatalog(): Observable<Channel[]>{
      return this._channels;
   }
}
```

But the seed argument isn't return when I subscribe to the observable ex:

```
var channelsCatalog = new ChannelsCatolog();
channelsCatalog.getAllChannelsCatalog.subscribe((value) => console.log(value));
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at `startWith()` maybe that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The seed value of `.scan` is used for the first emission as accumulator. If no emissions have been done the scan operator does not execute.

You are looking for the `.startWith` operator which can be suffixed after your scan operator to let your stream upon subscription directly emit the value passed to startWith.

```
this._channels = this._updates
  .scan((channels: Channel[], operation: IChannelOperation) => operation(channels), initialChannel)
  .startWith(initialChannel)
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount();
```

You still need the seed of `.scan` otherwise after the initialChannel emission from `.startWith` it will take two emissions before the `.scan` will execute and return it's first value.